# Is it unrecommended to run Django on IIS?

Tags: django, windows, server, pyisapie

I'm going to run Django-based webpage on my not-using Windows labtop.

Some material that I found from web says that I have to use PyISAPIe to run Django on ISS but its last update day is 2009-06-17... You can see that here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyisapie/files/pyisapie/

Is it safe to use that such old module? Or can you let me know what I should do without PyISAPIe to run Django on Windows server?

Comment: A quick google points to [wfastcgi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi), which was last updated in August 2016 and seems to support WSGI on IIS. I've never used IIS, but maybe this will help.